# Where should I go to get insights into platform-specific assembly quirks?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I'm working on a project that involves some assembly programming, but I'm not sure if Stack Exchange is where I should be asking about it.

I posted a little while back, looking for help on Stack Exchange with how to optimally tackle a particular type of issue. It was found that my post was off-topic, but I wasn't left with any idea of where to more appropriately get such help.

I've got another one of those "This topic is unfamiliar to me. Is there a better way to go about it?" kind of questions, and I think I'm doing a better job of not turning it into an "I'm so frustrated at this language" rant than I did with my last question, but I still am unsure if Stack Overflow is the place to be asking it. I'm also pretty sure that I'm uncomfortable with the topic, and I'm looking for confirmation or adjustments to how I'm tackling the issue.

I'll include the final bit I planned to include, the paragraph with all the question marks, but I'm looking for the proper place to get help with this.

> There are some questions I don't well understand, let alone know how to answer. I was hoping the Stack Exchange community could help me better understand the following:
>
> 1. Does the Go compiler produce a markedly different binary on Linux vs Windows, or with ARM for an STM dev board vs a Raspberry Pi? Like, how much of a nightmare is it to consider supporting multiple platforms for library purposes? Does the compiled binary for specific functions change across versions? Would a heuristic model attending to moves, arithmetic, and comparisons have required update to move between any of the recent major versions of Go?
> 2. Suppose I'm being responsible, not blindly assuming that a pointery thing being passed to the initializer is a function code-point, what are some potential liabilities for a package like this? Are there any obvious exploits this technique opens the door to? Are there performance problems with reflecting on the binary itself?
> 3. Having read some background information for the Plan9 model and the documentation for the unsafe and x86asm libraries, is there anything you consider a must-read before modeling parts of the compiled binary?

So should I be asking about this in Stack Exchange or somewhere else?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure which Stack Exchange site you asked this on, but I'm going to guess that it was Stack Overflow.

At least on that site, the question that you would like to ask is off-topic, for a number of reasons:

- It needs more focus. I count 8 questions spread out across 3 categories. While there is definitely some connection between the questions, you still need to ask at most one of them.  Even individually, there are issues with the questions being too broad.
- Several, if not all, of the questions are opinion based, i.e. they are difficult to answer objectively. Soliciting opinions is not really suitable for the Q&A format.
- The 3rd question is seeking recommendations, which is off-topic on Stack Overflow. There are however several sites on Stack Exchange, such as Software Recommendations, and Hardware Recommendations, where recommendation questions are definitely on topic. You still need to make sure that the question is phrased in a way that is clear, focused, and is otherwise conformant to the site's requirements.

In general, I would say that the question is too broad for pretty much any Stack Exchange site. With some care, you *might* be able to split them up into multiple questions. Of course, each of those questions might be appropriate on different sites. You should always read the Help pages for that particular site to figure out what works there, before posting your question.

I can't really say which non Stack Exchange sites would be appropriate for asking your questions. Platforms that operate more as discussion forums, and welcome opinion based questions and answers, are probably what you're looking for. I've heard some positive things about Reddit and Quora, though I don't use them myself, and so I can't recommend them per se.